# What's the point of the Access-Control-Allow-Headers header

Tags: html, http, cross-domain, cors

I'm reading up on the [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) standard, and one thing didn't make sense to me.

Say I want to send a request from domain A to domain B, including an Authorization header. As I understand it, the server on domain B needs to accept this by sending the header Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

What's the point of this? I thought the Same-Origin Policy was meant to protect data from domain B from leaking to websites on domain A. I don't see how it matters which headers A sends to B.

Comment: this has been on my mind for some time now. I was wondering the same thing

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I think that most web apps are probably OK to just echo the Access-Control-Request-Headers. As a webdev/sysadmin, I'll let you know that a certain header isn't allowed when you actually try it; telling you in advance is a micro-optimization at best. But as a protocol designer, maybe I can imagine someone having a use for this feature. If I can find anything authoritative I'll be back to add an answer. (With all that has been written about CORS, why is this so hard to find??)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I think I have a possible answer:

Server B doesn't want malicious scripts on other websites to send it requests in the context of a logged in user.
Situation: 
So server B say gmail.com has Foo logged in.

Server A: malicioussite.com has a script that sends an xhr to gmail.com querying a list of mails

Since Foo is logged int gmail.com, gmail recognizes the session cookie and sends the list.

This is only possible if gmail.com has cross origin request policy allowed. Otherwise server A where the user Foo has inadverently gone cannot get data from Server B(gmail).

It is not to protect the hosting site(the site that sends xhr) because if site A knowingly wants some data to be sent to server B, there is no reason why it shouldn't. If there is a browser script/malware that is sending xhr from Server A's page, data is already compromised.

Thta's how it protects server B against XSS.

Comment: That makes sense. So if gmail was to allow CORS, they could disallow certain headers, and use those to detect whether or not the requests came from gmail.com.

Comment: although that is not a reliable method,  CORS deny pretty much blocks session hijacking via ajax. If session is not in question, and the attacker sends a curl request, or a browser request even, gmail really cannot tell if its a geniune xhr or somebody just spoofed it

Comment: Unless I'm misreading you, I disagree. It is the Access-Control-Allow-Origin mechanism that should stop the user's browser from executing the malicious xhr. Why would you attempt to use any header other than 'origin' for this purpose?

Comment: In fact, this is what the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header is for.

(I personally don't understand the threat model of Access-Control-Allow-Headers and very few people on the internet seem to have explained it. I get the abstract concept that browsers want to check any cross-site access that does anything fancier than what an `<img>` tag can do, but not what concrete problems could occur if you always reflect access-control-request-headers back.)

Answer (score 2):

Note that the entire reason the preflight request exists is to provide a guard for requests that you couldn't do before CORS. Every simple request (e.g. requests that don't require a preflight) can already be done using existing mechanisms. For example, a GET request with no custom headers is similar to a JSONP request, while a POST request with no custom headers is similar to a JavaScript form.submit().  Servers have to already be prepared to receive these types of requests from other domains, since they can be performed without CORS.

CORS introduces servers to a whole range of new HTTP methods and headers. In order to verify that servers are prepared to answer these requests, the notion of a preflight was introduced. The preflight verifies that the particular combination of HTTP methods/headers are allowed before sending the actual request to the server.

Why not send the actual request, and just prevent the client from receiving the response? The actual request may have a side-effect associated with it (for example, updating or deleting a database entry), and merely sending the request could trigger the side-effect.

Sending the preflight, and verifying HTTP headers, ensures that servers are not surprised by the new types of requests introduced by CORS.